# search range of alternating date and payment cells

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, date, paypal

Search a huge range

I have a huge range (O15:BJ9309) that contains alternating cells of dates and payments in each row (date, payment, date, payment, date, payment, etc.)  I need a formula that looks for dates that contain a specific year (ex. 2014) and adds up all payments to the immediate right of that date.

For example, in the range:

```
Date..............Pymt.......Date..........Pymt.....Date.........Pymt  
12/18/2013....$400.....1/2/2014....$750.....2/1/2014...$320
```

In the above example, it would add $750 + $320 because both payments were made in 2014, but ignore a $400 payment made in 2013.
I’ll insert this formula in a hidden table, adjusting it to search for subsequent years:

```
Tax Year.....Gross
2014...........$80,000
2015...........$75,000
2016...........$93,000
```

Once that’s in place, I want to insert two cells into my Date and Payment’s page header, one labeled “Tax Year” and the second “Gross.”   If “2015” is typed into the Tax Year cell, “$75,000 displays in the Gross cell.  So I need a formula for that, too.

Many Thanks!

Comment: If this is an Excel problem, can you remove the MySQL tag?

Comment: If everything was in 2 columns you could just =SUMIFS([paymentscolumn],[datecolumn],">=2014",[datecolumn],"<2015"). Why on earth would you store data over multiple columns like that?

Comment: this looks like an excel problem. if you are exporting it from a mysql select to excel then this can be done in mysql. the tags and title of post should be more relevant though. if you're looking for a mysql answer then just do `SELECT SUM(pymt), YEAR(date) FROM my_table GROUP BY YEAR(date)` and it'll do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Given that your first column is "odd" (#15), you can try this **array** formula:

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN(Rng),2)*(YEAR(Rng)=2014),OFFSET(Rng,0,1)))
```

Rng Refers to:  $O$15:$BJ$9309

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
**ctrl-shift** while hitting **enter**.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces {...} around the formula.

**Edit:**  If you replace the 2014 with a cell reference, you can vary the output easily according to the year of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have headers like those shown in row 14?

If so try using `SUMPRODUCT` like this

`=SUMPRODUCT((O14:BI14="Date")*(YEAR(O15:BI9309)=2014),P15:BJ9309)`